# angularjs chartjs legend undefined

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

Can anyone figure out why the legend is undefined?

here is a plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/uSbRpx5w7nHvGQ3OG3x2?p=preview

here is the code

```
   $scope.chartData = {
data: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
labels: [
  "Joe",
  "Jason",
  "Mark",
  "Mike",
  "Ryan",
  "Sean",
  "Stephanie"
],
series: ['Year 2016',]
```

};

i have made 2 examples.  the top one works, the one below it doesn't

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In charts the data-set must be an array of data, where the data in-turn  is itself an array 
i.e)`data-set: [data_1, data_2, data_3],` where `data_1=[1,2,3,4,5]; data_2=[45,32,12,25,12];..`

And the `series` represents the corresponds the data.

But here in your case the data-set is an array of numbers, which is why the legend becomes `undefined`.

```
$scope.chartData = {
 data: [[20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]],
 labels: [
  "Joe",
  "Jason",
  "Mark",
  "Mike",
  "Ryan",
  "Sean",
  "Stephanie"
 ],
 series: ['Year 2016' ]
};
```